# Toggle between different "Show Values As" options in Slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using a Matrix in PowerBI to show the Sales Manager and Sales Reps down the rows, and the different ship method and source of the order across the columns and a count of unique orders in the values.

Below shows the table structure I have, and I want to switch between "Show Values As": the original values I calculate with my measure (count of unique orders) and % of Row Total.

Currently, my only solution is to create a second table showing the different values, but I think that's a cheap solution. I've seen solutions with helper tables but since my values are a measure I cannot invoke them in other measures, and as the sources or ship methods are filtered I want the % of row total to reflect the filter as well so using a `countx` formula won't account for that (if I housed it in a formula).

I'm still somewhat new to the software so please bear that in mind.

```
                     Source 1        |        Source 2         |      Source 3
          |  Next Day; Ground; 2 Day | Next Day; Ground; 2 Day | Next Day; Ground; 2 Day 
+Manager 1| 
   Rep 1  |
   Rep 2  |
+Manager 2|
   Rep 1  |
   Rep 2  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the best solution for you is to create bookmarks. You can create two tables, one showing the values and the other showing the %. Position the tables such that, one table is exactly on top of the other. Then create two bookmarks, one showing Table1 and the other showing Table2 (while hiding the other table using the "Selection Pane"). You can then use the bookmarks in a button action to toggle between Value and % views. The following link should give you further details on bookmarks:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks

You can also do this by creating a measure which switches between values and %, but the formatting is going to be a pain point. I think bookmarks is your best bet.

Comment: Hi, I should've mentioned that the data is filtered by dates as well. As the information updates and the date filters are changed by users, do the bookmarks hold those filters constant too or do they remain as they are (or is that a setting I can adjust?)

Comment: You have an option to retain the filters or not retain them. You can choose to retain the filters.

Comment: I tried the bookmarks, and it doesn't seem to hold onto the changed "Show Values As", is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, I created one, then created the other. I think bookmarks are meant for filters in the data, not changing the values within a Matrix. For example, if I have one measure in, bookmark it, if I change that measure, the bookmark will keep the change for the previous bookmark.

Comment: What do you mean two tables? If i had two tables, why would I even need a bookmark? the objective is to have a user have a button they could click to change the matrix from displaying "% of Row Total" vs. "No Calculation" from the show values as

Comment: If you have two tables, the bookmark will let you show only the correct table (You can choose which table to display based on the selection). That's why I was suggesting that the tables be such that one is on top of the other exactly. This is a workaround I have used like a million times :)

Comment: From a user perspective, even though there are two tables, it would look like one table where the values change

Comment: Okay, makes sense. While it's a little hacky, and this may sound dumb, but if the visual is exactly beneath the other how do I even click it now?

Comment: You can use the selection pane to select the particular visualization. To access the selection pane, click on View --> Check the box selection pane

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parameter table (with no relationships to other tables in your model) to use as a slicer and a measure that switches between the two calculations based on a slicer selection.

Let's suppose you have measures `[OrderCount]` and `[OrderCount%Total]`. Then create a new table to use as a parameter `ParamMeasure` with a single column

```
Measure
-------
Count
%Total
```

You can now put `ParamMeasure[Measure]` as a slicer on your report and substitute the following measure instead of the existing ones.

```
OrderSwitch =
    IF (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( ParamMeasure[Measure] ) = "Count",
        [OrderCount],
        [Order%Total]
    )
```

This way you don't need to create multiple visuals and bookmarks.